# How do you add a conditional cooldown in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have developed an economy bot for Discord called [Infinix](https://top.gg/bot/847826926483013649/). I am currently developing a work command. Here is my current code:

```py
@bot.command(name='work')
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx, arg = None):
```

User should be able to view the work list using `!work list`. The problem here is that, it is also considered under the cooldown. Is there a way to set a conditional cooldown?